# Auto-generated static field in F# class/module prevents creation of SQL CLR function

Tags: sql-server, f#, static-members

I'm trying to write a CLR user-defined function in F#, but `CREATE ASSEMBLY` gives the error:

> CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because type 'StringMetrics' in safe assembly 'MyNamespace.SqlServer.Text' has a static field 'field1776@'. Attributes of static fields in safe assemblies must be marked  readonly in Visual C#, ReadOnly in Visual Basic, or initonly in Visual C++ and intermediate language.

Here's how it looks in Reflector. This is not a field I've explicitly created.

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
internal static <PrivateImplementationDetails$MyNamespace-SqlServer-Text>.T1775_18Bytes@ field1776@; // data size: 18 bytes
```

I've tried using a module and a class. Both generate the field, just in different places. What is this field for? Is there a way to avoid its creation? Is there another approach I should be using to create a CLR function in F#? Is it even possible?

#### Complete Code

```
namespace MyNamespace.SqlServer.Text

module StringMetrics =

    open System
    open System.Collections.Generic
    open System.Data
    open System.Data.SqlTypes

    [<CompiledName("FuzzyMatch")>]
    let fuzzyMatch (strA:SqlString) (strB:SqlString) =
        if strA.IsNull || strB.IsNull then SqlInt32.Zero
        else
            let comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase

            let wordBoundaries = [|' '; '\t'; '\n'; '\r'; ','; ':'; ';'; '('; ')'|]

            let stringEquals a b = comparer.Equals(a, b)

            let isSubstring (search:string) (find:string) = find.Length >= search.Length / 2 && search.IndexOf(find, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0

            let split (str:string) = str.Split(wordBoundaries)

            let score (strA:string) (strB:string)  =
                if stringEquals strA strB then strA.Length * 3
                else
                    let lenA, lenB = strA.Length, strB.Length
                    if strA |> isSubstring strB then lenA * 2
                    elif strB |> isSubstring strA then lenB * 2
                    else 0

            let arrA, arrB = split strA.Value, split strB.Value
            let dictA, dictB = Dictionary(), Dictionary()

            arrA |> Seq.iteri (fun i a ->
                arrB |> Seq.iteri (fun j b ->
                    match score a b with
                    | 0 -> ()
                    | s -> 
                        match dictB.TryGetValue(j) with
                        | true, (s', i') -> //'
                            if s > s' then //'
                                dictA.Add(i, j)
                                dictB.[j] <- (s, i)
                        | _ -> 
                            dictA.Add(i, j)
                            dictB.Add(j, (s, i))))

            let matchScore = dictB |> Seq.sumBy (function (KeyValue(_, (s, _))) -> s)
            let nonMatchA = 
                arrA
                |> Seq.mapi (fun i a -> i, a)
                |> Seq.fold (fun s (i, a) -> 
                    if dictA.ContainsKey(i) then s
                    else s + a.Length) 0
            let wordsB = HashSet(seq { for (KeyValue(i, _)) in dictB -> arrB.[i] }, comparer)
            let nonMatchB = 
                arrB |> Seq.fold (fun s b -> 
                    if wordsB.Add(b) then s + b.Length
                    else s) 0

            SqlInt32(matchScore - nonMatchA - nonMatchB)
```

Comment: I would browse the code with Reflector and try to find where that field is being used, then track it back to the F# code.

Comment: @Mauricio: Reflector says it's being used by `fuzzyMatch` but I can't find it.

Comment: @Daniel: by fuzzyMatch itself, or something within it?

Comment: @Mauricio: by `fuzzyMatch` itself

Comment: Since CLR just means "Common Language Runtime" and does not imply "SQL Server" it might make your question more clear if you mention that this is specifically about [SQL Server CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.80).aspx) compatibility.

Comment: @Joel: I thought the reference to `CREATE ASSEMBLY` along with the sql-server tag made it clear, but I updated the title nonetheless. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's generated by the `wordBoundaries` array. If you express it as a list instead, and convert it to an array at runtime, this internal static field is not generated:

```
let wordBoundaries = Array.ofList [' '; '\t'; '\n'; '\r'; ','; ':'; ';'; '('; ')']
```

However, it seems that also the function itself is represented as a static, non-readonly 
field:

```
public static SqlInt32 fuzzyMatch(SqlString strA, SqlString strB);
```

Maybe using a class instead of a module cures this.

Comment: Now it's failing on `System.LazyFailure` for the same reason. I'm thinking this is hopeless. Thanks for your help nonetheless.

Comment: @Daniel: you could configure SQL Server to accept unsafe assemblies.

Comment: @Mauricio: It's not up to me, but probably not. It's too bad, I would much rather write this in F#.

Comment: @Daniel: found this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlnetfx/thread/b85578df-1e93-4fa4-8398-da01ae769a0a which confirms it's currently not possible to write SQL-Server-safe F# assemblies :-(

Comment: @Mauricio: How sad. :-( Thanks for finding that.

Comment: For the record, it works fine if you are able to accept unsafe assemblies.